# mySQL SELECT query from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a help with mySQL SELECT query from multiple tables. I have got four tables: school, discipline, pupils and teams.

School table looks like:

```
+------+---------+---------------+----------+
| id   | name    | discipline_id | pupil_id |
+------+---------+---------------+----------+
| 1    | one     |     2         |    5     |
+------+---------+---------------+----------+
| 2    | two     |     3         |    8     | 
+------+---------+---------------+----------+
| 3    | three   |     4         |    12    | 
+------+---------+---------------+----------+
```

Discipline table looks like:

```
+------+---------+
| id   | name    | 
+------+---------+
| 1    | math    |
+------+---------+
| 2    | bio     |
+------+---------+
| 3    | liter   |
+------+---------+
| 4    | geo     |
+------+---------+
```

Teams table looks like:

```
+------+---------+---------------+-----------+
| id   | name    |   school_id   | member_id |
+------+---------+---------------+-----------+
| 1    | T1      |     1         |     3     |
+------+---------+---------------+-----------+
| 2    | T2      |     3         |     3     | 
+------+---------+---------------+-----------+
| 3    | T3      |     2         |     9     | 
+------+---------+---------------+-----------+
```

The result of disciplines I need to get with a "SELECT from discipline..."  query by "member_id = 3" is:

```
+-----------------+---------------+
| discipline_name | discipline_id |
+-----------------+---------------+
|      bio        |       2       |
+-----------------+---------------+
|      geo        |       4       |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

By matching member's school and then getting its discipline, if it makes sense...Is it possible to do with just one mySQL query?

Type of: member_id 3 => school_id 1,3 => discipline_id = show related disciplines names and ids which are 2, 4

Thank you very much...

Comment: Take a look at [mysql join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) commands?

Comment: so your `team-mamber_id` should match `school->puple_id`?

Comment: @Alex no it should match school_id and then discipline_id in those schools...I hope it makes sense...

Comment: @maxpelic I tried a few but cannot get the scheme right, sorry I am just a beginner... ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not clear or makes no sense to me.

But here is what you are literally asking for:

```
SELECT
       s.discipline_id
       d.name
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN school s
ON s.id = t.school_id
LEFT JOIN discipline d
ON d.id = s.discipline_id
WHERE t.member_id = 3
```